# SQL Alchemy - Transaction isn't working

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, spring-transactions, falcon

I am using the SQL Alchemy core version 1.1 and I can't seem to be able to get transaction working inside my falcon (python) application. I have followed the documentation to my knowledge correctly.

edit: database postgresql -> psycopg2cffi

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.__conn_url__ = settings.get_db_url()
    self.db_engine = create_engine(self.__conn_url__)
    self.db_engine.echo = False
    self.metadata = MetaData(self.db_engine)
    self.connection = self.db_engine.connect()
    self.organization_types_table = Table('organization_types', self.metadata, autoload=True)
    self.organization_type_names_table = Table('organization_type_names', self.metadata, autoload=True)

def post(self, json_data):
    transaction = self.connection.begin()
    print(transaction)
    try:
        results = self.organization_types_table.insert().\
            values(date_created=datetime.datetime.now()).\
            execute()

        organization_types_id = results.inserted_primary_key

        results = self.organization_type_names_table.insert().\
            values(organization_types_id=organization_types_id[0],
                   lang=json_data['lang'],
                   name=json_data['name']).\
            execute()

        transaction.commit()
        print("I didn't rollback")
        return results
    except:
        transaction.rollback()
        print("I rollback :D")
        raise
```

If I run this code multiple times inserting the same objects. It should only work for the first time due to a index constraint not allowing duplications.

The results I will get according to my print() statements:

1. Transaction object -> I didn't rollback
2. Transaction object -> I rollback :D
3. Transaction object -> I rollback :D

If I look inside my tables I can clearly see that `organization_types_table` contains 3 records while `organization_type_names` contains 1. Why isn't `organization_types_table` not rolling back according to the transaction?

Comment: What DB are you using? What is its default isolation level? For example, MyISAM on MySQL works in autocommit mode by default, which means no transactions.

Comment: @univerio postgresql -> psycopg2cffi

Comment: I think you need to do `self.connection.execute(query)` instead of `query.execute()`, the latter of which is equivalent to `self.db_engine.execute(query)`, which, in turn, acquires a new connection instead of using the one on which you have a transaction open.

Comment: @univerio it worked! do you want to post a answer to get the credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
self.connection.execute(query)
```

instead of

```
query.execute()
```

`query.execute()` executes `query` on the engine, which acquires a new connection, instead of using the one on which you have a transaction open.